# Python - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (A Small Program For Steam Item Price)

Tags: python, steam

So , i made this small program to update about the lowest_price of a specific item on steam market , it runs a loop and gets json response.

It works fine initially , displays the price , but after a while it shows the error.

The program code :

```
import json
import requests

def GetPrice () :

    response = requests.get ('https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=264710&currency=1&market_hash_name=Planet%204546B%20Postcard')

    json_data = {}
    json_data = json.loads (response.text)

    return json_data ["lowest_price"]

while True :

    print (GetPrice ())
```

Here is the output of the program :

```
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
$1.03
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\item_price.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (GetPrice ())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\item_price.py", line 12, in GetPrice
    return json_data ["lowest_price"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[Finished in 20.2s]
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you keep checking the same URL over and over again?

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when you are trying to index an object that is of type `None` (i.e: the object has no value).

Here your `None` object is your `json_data` variable, which means that `json.loads (response.text)` returns `None`.

You can avoid this error by adding an if statement that will check if the value is not `None`:

```py
if json_data is not None:
    return json_data['lowest_price']
return None
```

Or with a try-except statement:

```py
try:
    return json_data['lowest_price']
except Exception as e:
    return None    # or you can raise an exception if you want
```

Answer (score 3):

You're experiencing this problem since you're making too many requests to the server really fast.

To be specific, the server replies with http error code [429](https://httpstatuses.com/429)

Consider waiting for a few seconds before sending successive requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable holding correct data. if `json_data` holding nothing then you can not retrieve the value. Say, json_data is `None` you need to check the variable.

### Approach 1

```
try:
    return json_data["lowest_price"]
except Exception as e:
    print(json_data)
    print(e)
    return None
```

### Approach 2

You can check `json_data` variable value explicitly

```
if json_data != None:
    if "lowest_price" in json_data:
        return json_data["lowest_price"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So sometimes you are receiving empty response which is causing issue

```
try:
    price = json_data ["lowest_price"]
except Exception as e:
    pass
```